# $f$ can visit every real number ($\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}|f(t)|=0$) implies $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are infinite

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove the next:

Suppose that $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a right-continuous function with left limits and $f$ is non-zero. Then $f$ can visit every real number implies that $\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=\infty$ and $\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=-\infty.$

I'm stuck in this. I know the above holds, even is equivalent, when $f$ is continuous. So my feeling is this proposition is true.

As a way to express "$f$ can visit every real number", we can put this as $\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}|f(t)|=0.$

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\liminf_{t \to \infty}|f(t)| = 0$ is not the same as "$f$ can visit every real number". For example, the function $g(t) = 0$ has $\liminf_{t \to \infty}|g(t)| = 0$, but $g$ only visits $0$!

To prove the claim, here's a start: Because $f$ is right-continuous with left limits, for any $c$ the set $\{t : f(t) \geq c\}$ has a least element (can you see why?). What happens when you look at these least elements for $c = 1,2,3,4,$ and so on? That should get you to the limsup part.

Comment: Thanks to answer @Reese.You're right. My mistake. The hypotesis must be consider $f$ be nonzero. I'll edit it. Why the set $\{t:f(t)\leq c\}$ has least element? I can't see it. I was trying to prove the infimum of such set exists and belongs to the set.

Comment: I think I get that $\{t:f(t)\geq c\}$ has least element. The infimum of such set exists, we say $t_{0},$ because is not empty and is lower bounded. Then there exists a decrasing sequence of rational numbers $(t_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $t_{n}\rightarrow t_{0}.$ Because of the right continuity we get $t_{0}\in\{t:f(t)\geq c\},$ right @Reese?

Comment: I think I get it! Many thanks @Reese. I have other doubt:The condition $\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}|f(t)|=0,$ when $f$ is nonzero, will imply the thesis of the proposition? Thanks for the help and the patience.

Comment: I'm glad you've gotten it! And no, $\liminf_{t \to \infty}|f(t)| = 0$ tells you basically nothing - it just means, loosely, that $f(t)$ gets "small" infinitely often as $t$ gets big. For examples, $\liminf_{t \to \infty}|2^{-t}| = 0$, and $2^{-t}$ visits only positive numbers.